# Web 8 Custom Deployer - cd_broker.jar not found in Rest Deployer files

Tags: web8, storage-extensions

I noticed in the Web 8 Content Delivery / API role that the in-process lib folder contains a cd_broker.jar file, but the REST lib folder does not.  Any reason for this?

Also, the lib folder for the Deployer install files does not contain a cd_broker.jar file at  *Content Delivery\roles\deployer\standalone\lib*

How would I compile a Tridion 2011 Custom Deployer (Storage Extension) for Web 8?

I'm also using the new style publishing with TopologyManager.

Comment: Do you need the actual jar? or the classes? I would just give it a try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For REST API's, core components are present in content service. So, you can find  `cd_broker.jar` in `content\standalone\services\content-v2-service` folder.